# Passing data from Activity A to Activity D in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, save

Here is my problem:

Activity A has en EditText. I need to save the user's input from this EditText in order to pull it out in Activity D, 3 activities down the activity hierarchy, and throw it into a TextView I have set up there. I've tried several methods, but none have worked. The examples I have come across implement certain methods, like Bundles within intents, that push data to the very next Activity in the hierarchy. I believe these methods haven't worked for me because I'm having to push data to an Activity that is further down the hierarchy. Any suggestions?

Comment: What have you tried with Bundles and Intents? We might be able to give you some tips to get that to work correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to go the Bundle route, you can continually pass the same Bundle through your hierarchy of activities, or store the data from one Bundle into the next. You can also use SharedPreferences. It depends on whether the data needs to be persisted if the application is killed.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest thing would be make use from SharedPreferences that are accesible from every activity or service of your application.

Your are trying to transfer simple data, so it will be very simple to put into key-value pairs.

To save data into Sharedprefs just type in Activity that saves user data

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

editor.putString("key", "value");
editor.commit();
```

In activity that want to retrieve data, use this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
String userValue =  prefs.getString("key", "ValueIfKeyDoesNotExist");
```

There is of course much more to read about SharedPreferences - best source is official source [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

You can also try using database like SQLite, but in your case data that should be stored are pretty simple, so none of advantages of DBs will be noticed. 
Passing data through many Activities by Intent.putExtra() is also not very useful

Answer (score 0):

If it is just text (EditText) that you want to pull to a TextView later. I would look into setting up a SQLite Database class to save the text in a database then pull the text to TextView in any Activity. Here is a good link on setting : [SQLite for Android](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that the database is a pretty good idea.  If it is overkill, though, you might consider a static variable (perhaps even a list or a map) in a custom Application object.  Add an android:name=".MyApplication" attribute to the application element in your manifest, and then create a new class, MyApplication, that extends Application.  Once you do that, Activity A can call:

```
((MyApplication) getApplication()).setUserText(editText.getText().toString())
```

... and Activity D can call:

```
editText.setText(((MyApplication) getApplication()).getUserText()).
```

You'll have to work out the symantics of the message passing protocol: what happens if D is started before A, and so on, but this will get the string from one place to the other.